# Минификация кода собственной библиотеки

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

В проекте я использую собственную библиотеку, которую подключаю как модуль (`compile project`). Должен ли я в `build.gradle` библиотеки включать `minifyEnabled` в `true` или достаточно включить минификацию для `app`?

Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MinifyEnbled - это инструмент, который уменьшает размер вашего приложения,путем удаления неиспользуемого байткода.

Мне кажется достаточно использовать минификацию для app. Если в приложении, и как я понимаю в том числе и в библиотеке будут использоваться какие-либо неиспользуемые ресурсы, они просто отключаться.

Comment: По сути верно, для модулей типа library он не имеет никакого смысла.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию.